# Google chrome first request on fresh start take a long queuing time

Tags: google-chrome, timing, timing-diagram

For some weeks now (didn't happened before) Google Chrome takes a long time to respond on first request.
To reproduce :

1. Close Google Chrome
2. Open Google Chrome
3. Open any website

The first request will take more than 10s, sometime 12s, sometimes 15s, sometimes 17s. All next requests are very fast.
This happends on all tabs, if i open many tabs, all will be blocked for sometimes and they will all be unblocked at the same time. They seem to all be blocked by the same thing.

I have the same behaviour in private mode (so no extension here)
I have no problem with firefox.
Same behaviour with Edge Chromium.
On windows 11 22H2

Once the first request is fullfilled all next one will works like a charm very fast.

Waiting on first request :
[image: waiting first request]

Once first request is finished, see timings :
[image: first request is finished, the timings]

The same request with a new tab on a "warm" browser :
[image: new tab and fast answer]

Comment: Your question doesn't belong here and should be moved to [super user](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: at first i thought it was a server problem, not a client one. Sad to see you -1 my question :/ Hope this will help people anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the same timings in Edge Chromium, I have noticed another line : proxy negociation.

(sorry screenshot in french)

[image: proxy negociation]

So i went in computer configuration and un checked the "auto configure proxy settings".

[image: uncheck this box]

Problem fixed !

Comment: Thanks! It worked perfectly!! But why does windows set the proxy like this?

Comment: i still don't know why this happends :/ i noticed this with pfsense appliance, may be this is linked ?